# A mistaken proof that CDFs are not right-continuous

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, cumulative-distribution-functions

While trying to prove that CDFs are right-continuous, I wrote the following proof which seems to actually prove that CDFs are right-continuous if and only if the measure of the given point is zero.  I’m certain I’ve made some illicit move, but I can’t spot where.

---

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\Bbb R$, and define $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x)$.  Let $a\in\Bbb R$.  Then
$$\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+} (\mu(-\infty,a)+\mu[a,x)) = F(a)+\lim_{x\to a^+} \mu [a,x)$$
And the limit is the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu[a,a+1/n)$ which by the continuity of measure is $\mu(\{a\})$.  So $F$ is right-continuous if and only if $\mu(\{a\})=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define $F(x)=\mu(-\infty, x)$ then it is left-continuous (and is also right-continuous only if $\mu(\{a\})=0$), so your proof is correct.  The problem is your definition. Usually the CDF is defined as $F(x)=\mu((\infty,x])$, which **is** right-continuous.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense--tracing the source of the mistake, my professor's handwriting is hard to read.  :)